# Very specific vectorisation in R

Tags: r

Update: This was not precise enough. What I actually have is 4 vectors representing x and y coordinates of 2 sets of points and a function, which gives one number as output for each pair of points (that is, one point coming from each set). I would like to write this computation without using for loops.

For example

```
     x1=c(0,1,2,3)
     y1=c(4,5,6,7)
     x2=c(1,3,5,7)
     y2=c(2,4,6,8)
     f=(x1+y1+x2)/y2
```

Comment: `outer(x, y)` ? Or `x %o% y` ?

Comment: Is there a way to do it for more than 2 vectors?

Comment: What would be your desired output of more than 2 vectors?

Comment: perhaps check `expand.grid`

Comment: it would help to know whether `f` is vectorised

Comment: No, sorry, I was not precise enough. Here is my actual problem. I have 4 vectors, representing x and y coordinates of 2 sets of points. I have a function that is meant to give an output for each pair of points. So I will need just one matrix as output, but I have 4 vectors of input.

Comment: @user132290  Please do update it in the post along with a reproducible example and desired output.

Comment: I just updated the initial post

Comment: Use backticks rather than `$...$` in SO markup.

Comment: It seems like there are no formal issues anymore.

Comment: @user132290 What is the expected dimension of output matrix?

Comment: It will be a 4x4 matrix. For each pair of points, one number.

Comment: @user132290  Sorry, it is not clear for me.  If you can show the expected output, would be great

Comment: You say "pair of points" but your function uses 4 values.  You really should elaborate more on what you mean and give example output for your example input.

Answer (score 1):

May be this helps

```
f1 <- function(i,j) (x1[i]+y1[i]+x2[j])/y2[j]
outer(seq_along(x1), seq_along(x2), f1)
#    [,1] [,2]     [,3]  [,4]
#[1,]  2.5 1.75 1.500000 1.375
#[2,]  3.5 2.25 1.833333 1.625
#[3,]  4.5 2.75 2.166667 1.875
#[4,]  5.5 3.25 2.500000 2.125
```

#### Benchmarks

```
 set.seed(21)
 x1 <- sample(1:20,1e3,replace=TRUE)
 x2 <-  sample(1:30, 1e3, replace=TRUE)
 y1 <- sample(1:20,1e3, replace=TRUE)
 y2 <- sample(1:40,1e3,replace=TRUE)

 akrun <- function() {f1 <- function(i,j) (x1[i]+y1[i]+x2[j])/y2[j]
            outer(seq_along(x1), seq_along(x2), f1)}

 library(proxy)
 JH <- function(){f <- function(a,b) (a[1]+a[2]+b[1])/b[2]
                dist(cbind(x1,y1),cbind(x2,y2),method=f)}

 library(microbenchmark)
 microbenchmark(akrun(), JH(), unit='relative', times=20L)
 # Unit: relative
 # expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 #akrun()  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000  1.00000    20  a 
 #   JH() 60.40066 58.46018 58.08219 58.49396 57.10239 55.18854    20  b
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is a "distance matrix" based on a user-defined distance function. You can do this easily using `dist(...)` in package `proxy`.

```
f <- function(a,b) (a[1]+a[2]+b[1])/b[2]
library(proxy)
dist(cbind(x1,y1),cbind(x2,y2),method=f)
#      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]    
# [1,] 2.500000 1.750000 1.500000 1.375000
# [2,] 3.500000 2.250000 1.833333 1.625000
# [3,] 4.500000 2.750000 2.166667 1.875000
# [4,] 5.500000 3.250000 2.500000 2.125000
```

Answer (score 0):

> mapply(FUN=function(x1,y1,x2,y2)(x1+y1+x2)/y2, x1=c(0,1,2,3),
>   y1=c(4,5,6,7), x2=c(1,3,5,7), y2=c(2,4,6,8))

```
[1] 2.500000 2.250000 2.166667 2.125000
```

Comment: According to the OP, the result should be 4x4 matrix.  Your result seems like the `diagonal` of my solution

Comment: well ... it is not my understanding, to be  honest. i may be wrong.

Comment: I was also not sure about the solution, but the OP responded to my comments about the dimension.